# How to import a Bitbucket repo into my Github account?

Tags: github, version-control, bitbucket

I have a large repo on Bitbucket that I need to import into Github. The repo contains a ton of historical information that I do not want to lose. I've googled around and can't find a definitive resource which explains the process. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something obvious?

In many cases simply adding a new remote and pushing to it will do what you want:

```
git remote add github git@github.com:user/repo.git
git push github master
```

This will push your `master` branch to GitHub. You can push other branches in a similar manner, and you can push your tags with `git push github --tags`.

A more comprehensive option is to use the `--mirror` option, e.g.

```
# Add the github remote as above, then
git push --mirror github
```

From [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> `--mirror`
>
> Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under `refs/` (which includes but is not limited to `refs/heads/`, `refs/remotes/`, and `refs/tags/`) be mirrored to the remote repository. Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end, and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end. This is the default if the configuration option `remote.<remote>.mirror` is set.

Note that this implies `--force`, so be careful with it. Some users like to do this from a new bare clone of the remote (i.e. first do `git clone --bare git@bitbucket.com:user/repo.git`, then do the rest of the steps from the newly created bare repository).